# Is $\mathbb{P}T^*M$ a sub-Riemannian manifold if $M$ is Riemannian?

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, contact-geometry, sub-riemannian-geometry

*(this question is about a particular aspect of [a previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/229825/22606), which was not duly stressed)*

Let $(M,g)$ a Riemannian $n$-dimensional manifold, and let
$$
\widetilde{M}:=\mathbb{P}T^*M
$$
be the $(2n-1)$-dimensional manifold of tangent hyperplanes to $M$.

> QUESTION: Is $\widetilde{M}$ a sub-Riemannian manifold in a canonical way?

**Remarks & my own partial answer.**

Obviously, $\widetilde{M}$ is a contact manifold. Let $H\in T^*M$ be a tangent hyperplane, and denote by $\tau:\widetilde{M}\to M$ the canonical projection: then
$$
C_H:= \tau_\ast^{-1}(H)\subset T_H\widetilde{M}
$$
is the contact plane at $H$.

By definition, $C_H$ fits into the exact sequence
$$
0\to (H^*\otimes H^\perp)\to C_H\stackrel{\tau^*}{\to} H\to 0\, ,
$$
where $H^*\otimes H^\perp$ is the vertical tangent space to $\widetilde{M}$ at $H$. Now both the endpoints are equipped with a metric, essentially obtained from the restricted metric $g|_H$ and its dual (the "twisting line" $H^\perp$ can be normalised and hence neglected), so I figured that I can claim that $C_H$ possesses a unique metric which makes both arrows metric-preserving (when $TM$ is trivial, my reasoning certainly works).

If the answer to my question is positive, I would appreciate a link to the existing literature on the subject.

Comment: Yes. Each point of the projectivized cotangent bundle is a hyperplane in the underlying manifold, so use the pullback metric on that hyperplane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also believe that the answer to your question is yes, but I think that things are more complicated than indicated in the answer by @Ben_McKay and in your partial solution. The point is that while you have an exact sequence of the form claimed in your answer, requiring that the two arrows are metric does not pin down an inner product on the middle term. Essentially, the inner products which have this property are parametrized by all splittings of the sequence. (A metric gives a splitting via mapping the quotient back to the orthocomplement of the subspace and a splitting gives a metric by declaring the subspace and the image of the split to be orthogonal to each other.) You can use the Levi-Civita connection to split the corresponding sequence on the level of $TT^*M$ and then prove that this descends to the projectivization.

Comment: You're right - I've been sloppy about the construction of the metric on $C_H$. Nevertheless, the example I had in mind does not suffer from my sloppiness, since it deals with the case when $M$ is a Lie group, and more precisely the 3-sphere. In this case, $\mathbb{P}T^*S^3=S^3\times\mathbb{RP}^2$, and $C_H=H\oplus (H^\perp\otimes H^*)$, and then $S^2C_H^*=S^2H^*\oplus\mathrm{End}(H)\oplus (S^2H\oplus H^{\perp\ast\otimes 2})$ clearly contains the distinguished element $g|_H+g^\sharp|_{H^*}$ (the twisting factor $H^{\perp\ast\otimes 2}$ can be forgotten)...

Comment: ... but my *real question* is another: why do we take the *sum* $g|_H+g^\sharp|_{H^*}$ and not, e.g., the *difference* of the two metrics on $H$ and $H^*$, in order to define the metric on $C_H$? And, most importantly, $\mathrm{id}_H\in\mathrm{End}(H)$ is also a metric on $C_H$. In other words, I suspect that there is more than one way to define a sub-Riemannian structure on $S^3\times\mathbb{RP}^2$, i.e., that we are in presence of a "multi-sub-Riemannian structure". So, my real curiosity is: *how many $S^3$-invariant metrics exist on the contact distribution of $S^3\times\mathbb{RP}^2$?*

Comment: I think there are many $S^3$-invariant sub-Riemannian metrics on $\mathbb PT^*S^3$, even if you require them to be appropriately related to a fixed left invariant metric on $S^3$ (and there are quite a few of those already). Basically, these sub-Riemannian metrics should be parametrized by smooth sections of an appropriate bundle over $\mathbb{RP}^2$, so they should form an infinite dimensional space.

Comment: Again, you're right: the Killing form does not induce a metric, but rather a conformal class of them. Nevertheless, I could begin with the Euclidean metric on $S^3$, i.e., the restriction of the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^4$. I keep suspecting that $\mathbb{P}T^*S^3$ is equipped with a distinguished family of contact sub-Riemannian structures, and that this family is of rank two (i.e., described by the sections of a rank-two bundle), and there should be an easy representation-theoretic way to see it... but I just cant't see it!

Comment: I am not sure whether you are looking for the most general sub-Riemannian metric compatible with a metric on $S^3$ or if you are looking for natural conditions to pin it down as much as possible. In the latter case, my guess would be that the parameter space is sections of a rank 4 bundle on $\mathbb RP^2$ (parametrizing splittings of the sequnce). To pin it down further, you can require invariance under the isometry group $O(4)$ of $S^3$. This acts transitively on $\mathbb PT^*S^3$, which should lead to a unique solution (coming from the natural metric on the cosphere bundle).

Comment: Interesting point. Incidentally, are you claiming that $\mathbb{P}T^*S^3=\mathrm{O}(4)/\mathrm{O}(2)$? Or, stated differently, that there is an $S^1$-bundle over $\mathbb{P}T^*S^3$ isomorphic to $\mathrm{O}(4)$?

Comment: Yes, $O(4)$ acts transitively on $S^3$ by isometries with isotropy group $O(3)$. This in turns acts transitively on unit sphere of the tangent space on the base point and hence also on its projectivization. Hence $O(4)$ acts transitively on $\mathbb PTS^3$ with isotropy group $O(2)\times\mathbb Z_2$. Alternatively, you can start with $SO(4)$ and get to isotropy $O(2)$. Invariant metrics are then equivalent to $O(2)$-invariant inner products on the representation inducing the homogeneous vector bundle $H$. So even if you fix the metric on the base, there should be one more free parameter.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Each point of the projectivized cotangent bundle is a hyperplane in the underlying manifold, so use the pullback metric on that hyperplane. I don't have a reference, but I think this is probably in Montgomery's nice book. http://www.ams.org/books/surv/091/

Comment: Thanks for the reference - though it'll be hard to dig out what I need.